# Transpose a matrix using sed

Tags: matrix, shell, sed

I'm trying to transpose the following data from:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

to:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

using `sed` only please.

I have a working solution but I'm sure it can be improved:

```
sed -rn 'H;${x;s/\n/ &/g;s/$/@/;:a;s/\n([^ ]+ ?)(.*@.*)/%\2\1/;ta;s/ %+@//p;t;s/ *$/\n/;y/%/\n/;ta}'
```

It uses `%` and `@` for newline and end-of-string delimiters which may be problematic.

Comment: Any reason you are limiting the solution to `sed`?  What about `awk`?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Kristian I was unaware of the site.

Comment: @Yzmir I'm sure there are many published solutions in other languages but I am trying to improve my understanding of `sed`. BTW @Dave this is not homework per se just personal curiosity.

Comment: Will the columns for each line be the same?  Will the row count always match the column count?  Will a single space be the delimiter?

Comment: @Yzmir for the moment lets go with the input data provided above. That is 10x10 square matix each value delimited by a single space. But of course is should work for bigger or smaller matrices and 4x3 or 7x9 should work to. Tabs can be catered for by pre and post formating using `tr` or `sed`.

Comment: This is a better fit back on SO than here on cg

Comment: Or actually, even better on codereview.

Comment: Dubious as a code review question, here we like code you can read.

Answer (score 2):

This yet another way to do it:

```
sed -r '1{s/$/ /;s/ / \n/g};:a;$!N;s/$/ /;:b;s/\n(.*\n+)(\S+\s)/\2@!@\1/;tb;s/@!@/\n/g;${s/ \n/\n/g;s/\n+$//;q};ba'
```

This method is somewhat faster and only uses single delimiter which may be crafted to be unique. i.e. `@!@` in this example